# How I display 2 words before and after a key search word in Python

Tags: python

Very new to Python programming.  How I display 2 words before and after a key search word.  In below example I am looking for a search word = lists

Sample:

```
Line 1: List of the keyboard shortcuts for Word 2000
Line 2: Sequences: strings, lists, and tuples - PythonLearn
```

Desired results (Lists word only found only in line 2)

```
Line 2: Sequences: strings, lists, and tuples
```

Thanks for your help in this.

Comment: Did you want to print the whole line or only the words before and after the keyword?

Comment: Just want to print words before and after. It would be great if I have a flexability to change those words from 2 to 5 etc.

Comment: Why the desired output won't contain `PythonLearn` ?

Comment: in my example, two words after lists are...and tuples. I thought PythonLearn is 3rd word. Is it make sense?

Comment: @AvinashRaj he's searching for `lists`, and wants two words to the left (`Sequences` `strings`) and two words to the right (`and` `tuples`)

Comment: That is correct. Two words left and two words right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is based on Avinash Raj's second example with these amendments:

- Allows the number of words to be printed each side of the search word to be varied
- Uses a list comprehension instead of `if` inside `for`, which may be considered more 'Pythonic', though I'm not sure in this case if it's more readable.

.

```
s = """List of the keyboard shortcuts for Word 2000
Sequences: strings, lists and tuples - PythonLearn"""
findword = 'lists'
numwords = 2

for i in s.split('\n'):
    z = i.split(' ')

    for x in [x for (x, y) in enumerate(z) if findword in y]:
        print(' '.join(z[max(x-numwords,0):x+numwords+1]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is wonderful!!! I much appreciate your help in this. All are great solutions.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same find words along with numwords =2 just in 3rd field (text field)? I want to keep two fields without change for ref. integrity.My input file:
12088|CITA|{Hello very nice lists, better to keep those
12089|CITA|This is great theme for lists keep it 
My desired output file:

12088|CITA|very nice lists, better to 
12089|CITA|theme for lists keep it

Comment: Do you mean you want to output the whole of the input line up to the search word, then the next two words? Just replace `max(x-numwords,0)` in the last line with `0`. Or have I misunderstood what you're after?

Comment: In my given file, I want to search in 3rd column. And want to keep1st and 2nd columns as it is...is it possible                                     12088|CITA|{Hello very nice lists, better to keep those 12089|CITA|This is great theme for lists keep it                                   My desired output file: 12088|CITA|very nice lists, better to 12089|CITA|theme for lists keep it

Comment: So use `split('|')` to separate the columns, apply the technique above to the third column, then `join` to put them together again. I think you can figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

Through `re.findall` function.

```
>>> s = """List of the keyboard shortcuts for Word 2000
Sequences: strings, lists, and tuples - PythonLearn"""
>>> re.findall(r'\S+ \S+ \S*\blists\S* \S+ \S+', s)
['Sequences: strings, lists, and tuples']
```

**Without regex.**

```
>>> s = """List of the keyboard shortcuts for Word 2000
Sequences: strings, lists, and tuples - PythonLearn"""
>>> for i in s.split('\n'):
        z = i.split()
        for x,y in enumerate(z):
            if 'lists' in y:
                print(z[x-2]+' '+z[x-1]+' '+z[x]+' '+z[x+1]+' '+z[x+2])


Sequences: strings, lists, and tuples
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I can think of right away for your question :-)

```
def get_word_list(line, keyword, length, splitter):
    word_list = line.split(keyword)
    if len(word_list) == 1:
        return []
    search_result = []
    temp_result = ""
    index = 0
    while index < len(word_list):
        result = word_list[index].strip().split(splitter, length-1)[-1]
        result += " " + keyword
        if index+1 > len(word_list):
            search_result.append(result.strip())
            break
        right_string = word_list[index+1].lstrip(" ").split(splitter, length+1)[:length]
        print word_list[index+1].lstrip(), right_string
        result += " " + " ".join(right_string)
        search_result.append(result.strip())
        index += 2
    return search_result

def search(file, keyword, length=2, splitter= " "):
    search_results = []
    with open(file, "r") as fo:
        for line in fo:
            line = line.strip()
            search_results += get_word_list(line, keyword, length, splitter)
    for result in search_results:
        print "Result:", result
```